# Upgraded from 19.04 to 19.10 and now have disk errors

Tags: 19.10, fsck

After upgrading, I am no longer able to run the OS; it takes me to a black screen saying:

```
/dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY
fsck exited with status code 4
the root filesystem on dev/sda2 requires a manual fsck
```

I have also tried running in safe mode, but same thing happens.

Can anyone advise what I can do here?

Comment: It says: "RUN fsck MANUALLY" So do that. From a live session or from grub rescue.

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, open a terminal window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2`. Repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors, then reboot and update your question with the results.